# UNION queries with different number of columns?

Tags: postgresql, union

I have 2 queries on a table:

```
SELECT *, 1 as query_cr_0 FROM invoices LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON customers.id = invoices.customer_id WHERE (customers.id IN (64, 66, 63, 62, 65))

SELECT *, 5 as query_cr_1 FROM invoices WHERE (invoices.state IN ('ready', 'out_for_delivery', 'delivered', 'closed')
```

I want to fetch all invoices that fulfill either of the queries.

My approach was to use `UNION` but `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the first query prevents this:

> ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns

My second approach was to use something like this:

```
select invoices.id from invoices
where id in (SELECT invoices.id, 1 as query_cr_0 FROM invoices 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON customers.id = invoices.customer_id
             WHERE (customers.id IN (64, 66, 63, 62, 65)))
OR id in (SELECT invoices.id, 5 as query_cr_1 FROM invoices 
          WHERE (invoices.state IN ('ready', 'out_for_delivery', 'delivered', 'closed')))
```

But this throws an error:

> subquery has too many columns

My purpose is to fetch the invoices with `query_cr_0` and `query_cr_1` value. For ex: An invoice might be satisfying both the conditions so in that case both `query_cr_0` and `query_cr_1` should be present. If an invoice satisfies only one of the queries corresponding `query_cr` must be present.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You really should not use `*`.
But if you want to use it anyway, write `SELECT invoices.*, 1` to prevent the columns from the `customers` table from showing up.

Doing an outer join is pointless because any resulting rows that have NULL in `customer.id` would be filtered out by the WHERE.

And you do not actually need the join, because you have the customer ID value already in the `invoices` table:

```
SELECT ... FROM invoices WHERE customer_id IN (64, 66, 63, 62, 65)
```

---

Your second approach would work if you removed the second column (`1` or `5`) from the subqueries.

---

If you want the  `1`/`5` values to show up in the result, then you must use your first approach (and you can use UNION ALL instead of UNION because there will not be duplicate rows).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this had better be written as

```
  SELECT invoices.id FROM invoices
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customers
                WHERE customers.id = invoices.customer_id
                  AND customers.id IN (64, 66, 63, 62, 65))
UNION
  SELECT invoices.id FROM invoices
  WHERE invoices.state IN ('ready', 'out_for_delivery', 'delivered', 'closed');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the proper query for your case:

```sql
SELECT i.id AS customer_id
     , CASE WHEN c.id IS NOT NULL
            THEN 1 END AS query_cr_0  -- satisfies 1st query
     , CASE WHEN i.state IN ('ready', 'out_for_delivery', 'delivered', 'closed')
            THEN 5 END AS query_cr_1  -- satisfies 2nd query
FROM   invoices i
LEFT   JOIN customers c ON i.customer_id IN (64, 66, 63, 62, 65)
                       AND c.id = i.customer_id
WHERE  c.id IS NOT NULL  -- satisfies 1st query
OR     i.state IN ('ready', 'out_for_delivery', 'delivered', 'closed');  -- satisfies 2nd query
```

This returns *one* instance of each qualifying row in `invoices` and adds two columns (`query_cr_0` and  `query_cr_1`), where either one or both can have a value. The columns might as well be `boolean`, but I kept  1 / 5 like in your original.